# Can't Change Fadingedge length

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm trying to make the edges of a ScrollView Fading when there is more content, the problem is there is fading happening but it is very short and very hard to see even though I changed the fading edge length, this is the code I used to make the fading edge:

```
fullArticleScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.FullArticleScrollView);  
fullArticleScrollView.setFadingEdgeLength(20);
fullArticleScrollView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
```

and this is the xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/FullArticleScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
tools:context="com.cloudappers.twocents.FullArticleActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullArticleTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/articleContentTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I'm testing on Android 4.2